# SHA-2 issues with Verisign root on OS 10.9 Mavericks?

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, openssl, symantec

I'm using a Secure Site Pro with EV certificate from Verisign/Symantec, with a full SHA-2 root chain.

Everything is great - except for Mac OS 10.9 (Mavericks), that complains the certificate is signed by an untrusted authority.

This is not occuring in OS 10.10 (Yosemite), Android, IE11 or any other environment I've tested. I've tried and replicated the error on two different and entirely separate OS 10.9 instances.

This is the intermediate cert I'm using:

https://knowledge.verisign.com/support/ssl-certificates-support/index?page=content&actp=CROSSLINK&id=AR2054

Anyone else had this issue? I can't find a single reference on Google.

**Edit:**

URL in question is http://fundary.com

Comment: What's the url in question?

Comment: @EEAA updated the question to show the URL... we're testing this throughout the day so it may change in the meantime, but it's right now